# Create a custom theme-specific page, invisible in the admin-panel?

Tags: php, theme-development, themes, pages, page-template

I've learned that when I want a custom page, I need to create a page template, create my page and assign the template to it. Also I've read about fake/virtual pages, where the page is generated on the fly - which is not what I want, because the page I'd like to create is pretty static (it's a list of categories).

Is there a way to assign my own .php file as a custom page in WordPress, **which can't be seen** in the *All Pages* list in the admin panel, but can be linked to in a menu? The file is stored in my theme folder and I'm hoping to have it in a portable state, so that this custom page appears on every installation of the theme (regardless of the WP backend).

---

**EDIT** As expected, some other dude was facing the same problem. [Here, he solved it by creating the page and then make it invisible.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142884/hide-certain-pages-posts-on-wp-admin-show-custom-filter/143106#143106) The reason why you'd want this is: When an admin erroneously deletes said page, the site would break (or wouldn't make sense any more). I hope this makes my motivation more clear.

Although I could solve it like in the link above, is there a way to also make the .php file portable?

Comment: what kind of admin do not want to see all the site content? this sounds like a very bad idea even if it is possible to do it, or like you are trying to use the wrong tool for whatever you are actually trying to do.

Comment: It's really something that's important to the theme and should **always** be in place. The page I want to create should not be edited or deleted, and with that said, there's no need for it to be visible. I've edited the post where I refer to a similiar question, but my intent is to have it portable, so when it's installed on another WP installation, the page should also be there automatically.

Comment: if a piece of content should always be in place then you are doing something wrong as it means it is not content.